# How to grab only the 2nd-level domains from a list of subdomains

Tags: text-processing

### What I need

I have a list of domains like so:

```
a.example.com
b.foo.com
a.b.bar.com
```

I only want the output to grab the second-level domains and nothing else, i.e., no 3rd-level or higher. This is what I'm looking for from my example list above:

```
example.com
foo.com
bar.com
```

### What I tried

I've tried using `sed`, `awk`, and `cut` as follows:

**sed**

```
cat domains.txt | sed 's/\.$//g'
cat domains.txt | sed -r 's/^(.*)_/\1\\/; s/.$//g'  # this removes the last character for some reason
```

**awk**

```
awk '{ sub(/\.$/, ""); print $NF }' domains.txt
cat domains.txt | awk -F\. '{print $1,$2}' | tr ' ' '.' # won't work since there are 4th level domains
```

**cut**

```
cat domains.txt | cut -d '.' -f[field] # won't work since there are 4th level domains
```

Comment: `rev domains.txt | cut -d . -f-2 | rev`

Comment: That was annoyingly easy... thank you so much for the comment, this worked!

Comment: you could use grep too: `grep -Po '[^.]+\.[^.]+$' domains`

Comment: `while IFS=. read -a a; do echo ${a[@]:(-2):2}; done < domains`, if the list is short, probably the one I use.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I am always down to learn different ways to do things. You've been extremely helpful!

Comment: @bac0n - ?pop those as an answer - it’s obviously been helpful!

Comment: The grep answer should also work with `-E`, nothing pcre-specific about that one.

Comment: @glennjackman Not sure if it's just me, but `-E` is in some cases almost x3 slower than `-P` especially redirection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases where you need to start your match from the right, you can use an end anchor `$` to fixate the pattern to the end of the line.

grep:

```
grep -Po '[^.]+\.[^.]+$' domains.txt
```

sed:

```
sed  's/.*\.\([^.]\+\.[^.]\+\)$/\1/' domains.txt
```

`awk` has a pre-defined variable named `NF` holding the number of fields for the current record. You may combine the `NF` variable with the field specifier `$` to reference the value instead.

awk:

```
awk -F . -vOFS=. '{print $(NF-1), $NF}' domains.txt
```

You can also reverse the text for commands like: `read` or `cut` that purely reads from left to right.

rev, cut:

```
rev domains.txt | cut -d . -f1,2 | rev
```

Bash only example:

```
while read -r; do \
    printf %s\\n ${REPLY/#${REPLY%.*.*}.}; \
done < domains.txt
```